# What can you say about the order of this element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am self-studying algebra and encountered the following problem:

> If $b^{-1}ab=a^2$ and $c^{-1}ac=a^3$ and $b,c$ has orders $4$ and $3$ respectively, what can you say about the order of $a$?

In a previous question I was asked to prove that $b^{-1}ab=a^2$ implies $b^{-n}ab^n=a^{2^n}$ so I can use that to deduce $a^{15}=1$. From this follows that the order of $a$ is either $15, 5, 3$ or $1$. Using this and the second equality gives us $(c^{-1}ac)^5=a^{15}$ and thus $c^{-1}a^5c=1$, which yields $a^5=1$. So either $a$ is the identity $1$ or $a$ has order $5$. What else can I say about the order of $a$?

Comment: The first identity implies $b = a^2$, so $a^8 = b^4 = 1$. Since we also have $a^5 = 1$ we can conclude $a = 1$. In light of user1332891's remark, there seems to be a typo somewhere, perhaps the first equation should be $b^{-1} a b = a^2$?

Comment: I think you have typos. You probably mean $a^{-1}ba=b^2$ implies $a^{-n}ba^n = b^{2^n}$. Or (more likely) with the $a$ and $b$ interchanged.

Comment: Oh, sorry I replaced $a$ and $b$. Fixing.

Answer (score 2):

The element $a$ must be trivial. Basically: $$a=c^3ac^{-3}=a^{27}=_5a^2\Rightarrow a=1$$
Note that the cyclic group of order $12$, $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, is a specific example of a non-trivial group where $a$ is trivial but $b$ and $c$ are not. Can you find the relevant $b$ and $c$?

A more theoretical reason of why $a$ must be trivial is as follows. Note that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_5)\cong \mathbb{Z}_4$. This means that if $a$ has order five then the action of the element $c$ (which as order three) on $a$ must be trivial. Hence, $a^3=a$, so $a$ cannot have order five, a contradiction.

Comment: But $c^{-1}ac = a^3$ with $c$ of order $3$ does not work if $a$ has order $5$. I wonder if there is still a mistake in the question, because $a$ has to be trivial.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah, yes, that was sloppy of me!